# Check email already existed from DB except the email of current login id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to check if an email exists in a DB table excluding the email of current login_id. I wrote a function below. I don't know how to check email from DB using PDO.

```
public function updateEmail(passwordDto $password, PDO $connection){
        $pass = null;
        $pass= $password;

        $pass_id = $pass->getId();
        $Pass_user_id= $pass->getUser_id();
        $pass_email= $pass->getEmail();
        $pass_status = $pass->getStatus();

        try{
            $conn = $connection;
            $user_id = $_SESSION['user']; 

            $sql_email = "select email from tb_password where user_id <> $user_id  ";
            $email = $conn->prepare($sql_email);
            $email->execute();
            $emailarray= Array();
            while ($result =  $email->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $emailarray[] = array('email' => $result['email']);
            }


            if ( $result['email'] == $pass_email ){ 
                return -1;
            }else {
                $sql = "update tb_password set  email = '".$pass_email."' where user_id= '".$user_id."' AND id= '".$pass_id."' "  ;
                $conn->exec($sql);
                return 1;
            } 

        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e;
            throw $e;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `SELECT email FROM tb_password WHERE email = ? AND user_id != ?`.

Comment: @jeroen Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do rowcount using this command:

```
$email->rowCount();
```

You should change the query into:

```
SELECT email FROM tb_password WHERE email = $pass_email AND user_id != $user_id
```

Then if the rowcount is > 0, the email already exists.

Comment: [PHP delusion #5: Extensive use of the number of rows returned by a SELECT query](https://phpdelusions.net/top#num_rows)

Comment: Thank you so much!